# How do you call c macros in julia

Tags: julia

I know you can call functions with ccall and get pointers to global symbols with cglobal. But how do you get access to macros?

For example I wan't to replicate this code

```
clock_t start = clock();
clock_t end = clock();
float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

How can I execute the CLOCKS_PER_SEC macro at the end?

Comment: How did you solve this problem eventually?

Comment: @DanGetz I gave up.

Comment: Did you actually try my suggestions? For example, the second answer works completely inside Julia, with no external complications? You could have always inserted the value on your setup manually

Comment: @DanGetz My question was on how to call c macros, the c code given was an example and your answer was an answer to the example, not how to generally call c-macros from julia. Note: Without compiling every macro by hand for every os.

Answer (score 1):

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a constant defined in the standard header file `time.h`.

It is much better to use the timing facilities available in Julia and keep the program in one language (as the great ones intended). But if you insist, you can create the following simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%ld\n",CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it using something like `gcc clocks_per_sec.c -o clocks_per_sec`.
And then run it from Julia using:

```
julia> clocks_per_sec = parse(Int,read(`./clocks_per_sec`,String))
1000000
```

It might be simpler to just get the number once and plug it as a constant in the Julia program assuming the system will run on the specific computer or will not be maintained for a long time with the external C dependency.

P.S. The Julia code is relevant to 0.7 version, on earlier version, use `readstring(...))` instead of `read(...,String)`.

Comment: If you are creating a whole C library to access from Julia, you can export the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` from the library (as you export functions, etc.)

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC is assumed to be a macro, not a constant.

Comment: @Nozdrum It is a macro constant (i.e `#  define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t) 1000000)` on my system. Additionally, a comment in the header file says: *The value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC is required to be 1 million on all XSI-conformant systems*. So basically, it is 1 million. If you manage to find a system with a different CLOCKS_PER_SEC, I will be surprised. In any case the external program approach **will still work**. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: On windows 7 64 bit, msvc ```#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)``` and clock_t is just a typedef for long. I agree that your solution would work, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: Instead of trying do things the Julia way, you are insisting on interfacing with C - not a good choice. The Julia way is (copy paste the following): `tic() ; println("do some stuff") ;  sleep(1) ; println("stuff done") ; seconds = toq()`

Comment: There is a reason that I did not choose your suggestion ( a reasonable one! ) as the solution, because it is not the answer to my question.

Comment: What would an answer to your question be? You do know that C macros are run by the C/C++ compiler? This means you cannot "run" a macro without running a C/C++ compiler (which is also part of the suggested answer here). The `tic`/`toq` solution implicitly runs the C/C++ compiler when Julia binary is compiled (and maybe uses CLOCKS_PER_SEC). If you would explain what you want to accomplish, perhaps the community can answer or see what other route you can take... sometimes the question is not the right one with the answer which would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, which stays inside Julia could be (try it out):

```
for i=1:10
    b = 10^i
    tic()
    s = 0
    start = ccall(:clock,Clonglong,())
    for i=1:b
        s+=i
    end
    t = toq()
    stop = ccall(:clock,Clonglong,())
    if t>1.0
        println("CLOCK_PER_SEC most probably is ",10^(round(Int,log10((stop-start)/t))))
        break
    end
end
```

This answer assumes `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a power of 10, which seems to be universally the case. Note the `for` loop inside is used to waste *process time* and not *wall time* which could simply be wasted with `sleep`.